# Querying SQL by GROUP, HAVING, recency etc

Tags: sql, postgresql

My 'call_logs' table have the fields : id, phone_number, call_dialed_time, is_success. (If a call to a phone_number fails, then we enter the record and try to call again later)

For each and every phone_number that hasn't been successfully dialed yet, I want to get phone_number and call_dialed_time of the most recent failure.

How do I query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
select distinct phone_number ,call_dialed_time from call_logs where phone_number not  in(
select phone_number from call_logs group by phone_number having count(is_success) >0
)  order by call_dialed_time
```

Comment: It doesn't check if a unique number has had a successful call. If that number ever had successful call, I don't want to show that in my result.

Comment: @AayushKarki I updated query, try it and let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 select t1.* from call_logs as t1 inner  join 
 (
 select 
 phone_number, max(call_dialed_time) as call_dialed_time from call_logs
 where is_success=0
 group by phone_number
 ) as t2 on t1.phone_number=t2.phone_number and t1.call_dialed_time=t2.call_dialed_time
```